# Is there anyone know to do the reverse hashing in the PayU Integration in Android

Tags: android, payu

I am trying to integrate Payu Payment gateway and I am not able to generate the reverse hashing. Can anyone help me with the same.

Comment: Have you considered using the [official SDK](https://github.com/PayU/openpayu_php)?

Comment: @Niraj Yes I have considered the official SDK and it seems to have a method in the sdk which generates hashes from SDK and the hashes are generated successfully. But I am not able to find anything related to reverse hashing